# Calendar onSelectedDayChange and sqlite sum

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have Calendar view and a text view on a class, Ive formatted the calendar on **`onSelectedDayChange`** to **`yyyymmdd (which is the format of my datestamp database names)`**

How can I fetch a data of particular selected date? Like if i select january 01,2017 on calendar view then it will fetch data from that table?

Here is my codes to fetch the sum of **column Fat** for the current day only,

**This is on my mainactivity class**

```
public Integer totalFat()
    {
        repo repo = new repo(this);

        double i = repo.totalFatrepo();

        Textbreakfast.setText(""+i);

        return null;
    }
```

**This is on my repo class**

```
public double totalFatrepo(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM " + breakfast.TABLE;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        //Add in the movetofirst etc here? see SO
        c.moveToFirst();
        double i=c.getDouble(0);

        return i;

    }
```

What i want is if i click any dates on calendar view, it will fetch from db and display the data associated with that date.

> -----Edit for additional codes------

This is my db helper class. How can i format it to read the **setOnDateChangeListener** value?

```
public static String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = getDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

I save a timeOfDay calendar timeInMillis value with a std hour, minute, sec and millisec to isolate it to the day, basically i set it to 4am or something. then i can do a simple comparison on that value.

```
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE day >= " + thisDate + " AND day < " + thatDate;
```

OR

```
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE day = " + thisDate
```

So long as you set the hour, minute, second and millisec it works.

Comment: How can I get the sum (fat) from date where tablename =breakfast.table and columnName = Fat?

**//date = is the value of onselectedDay of calendar view//**

String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM" + date +

idont know where i will put my table name and column name..

Comment: Bye the way sir, ive edited my post, i added my db helper, i am just thinking of i need to format it to get the value of **setOnDateChangeListener** Please help me

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. It sounds like you need to google mysql CRUD Query to get a rough idea of how to work with databases in Android. `SELECT rows_you_want FROM table_rows_are_located WHERE some_conditional` In my example I used `SELECT * FROM TABLE` so basically it pulls me everything from the table. If you want a specific date look at the WHERE clause example. 'day' is a row in the table that holds the Long value for timeInMillis that is given from `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`.